# ¿Cómo capturo estos campos que son dinámicos en JavaScript y tiene el mismo nombre?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario que tiene 5 campos. Son 3 campos a llenar:
"Unidades" , "Descripción" y "Valor unitario". Y 2 campos que se calculan en base a multiplicar "Unidades" y "Valor Unitario".

Hasta ahí todo simple. El problema es que la cantidad de líneas es variable: 1 o más por cada formulario.

Por medio de JS duplico las líneas y van apareciendo o desaparaciendo en la medida que se necesitan y el usuario las puede llenar. Y guardo los datos en un BD. Pero cuando quiero calcular el Subtotal de la segunda línea (que aparece y puede desaparecer dinámicamente) no sé cómo identificarla. Asumo que hay que hacer una matriz con los datos y un ciclo para ir leyendo los datos. Pero ahí me complico entero.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);"  title="Agregar campos"> <i class="far fa-copy"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="form-group"><label  >Unidades</label>
                <input  type="number" id="unidades[]"   name="unidades[]" min="1" max="10000" maxlength="5"  value=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group"><label for="descripcion" class="form-label">Descripción</label>
                <input  type="text"   name="descripcion[]" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group"><label  >Valor Unitario</label>
                <input  type="text"  id="valorUnitario[]" name="valorUnitario[]" onchange="fnjs_habilitarBoton('idBoton'); fnjs_subtotal(this.value);"
                         ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group"><label >SubTotal</label>
                <input  type="text" id="subTotal[]"  name="subTotal[]" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group"><label for="valorMonedaCuba" class="form-label">Valor $ Cuba</label>
                <input  type="text"   name="valorMonedaCuba[]" id="valorMonedaCuba[]"  ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function fnjs_subtotal(valorUnitario)
{
   var unidades = document.getElementById('unidades[]').value;
   var subTotal ;
   subTotal = unidades * valorUnitario;
    document.getElementById('subTotal[]').value = subTotal;
    document.getElementById('valorMonedaCuba[]').value = subTotal * 24;
    largoMatriz = document.getElementById('subTotal[]').length;
}
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo del subtotal, no menciones lo que ya te funciono, ve al problea asi te podremos entender mejor

Comment: El problema es que no sé como identificar un campo, cuando al duplicarlos dinámicamente se  terminan llamando de la misma forma.   id="unidades[]",

Debo  permitir al usuario duplicarl los input dinámicamente y no puedo colocarle  id="unidades1",  id="unidades2",  id="unidades3" porque no se cuantos datos van a ser y además debo guardarlos en una base de datos. Pero antes de hacer eso, hay cálculos entre los campos que deben ocurrir antes de guardarlos en la BD y eso no se hacerlo.

            Unidades <input  type="number" id="unidades[]" name="unidades[]">

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te ayude, solo obtienes el valor del nombre como array y lo recorres por su longitud en un for

```js
document.getElementById("formmath").addEventListener("submit",function checkForm(){
event.preventDefault();
var input = document.getElementsByName('unidades[]');
var valueinput = document.getElementsByName('valorUnit[]');

var unidades=0;
var valor=0;
   
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
               unidades=unidades+ parseFloat(input[i].value);
               valor=valor+ parseFloat(valueinput[i].value);
               
            }
            console.log(unidades);
            console.log(valor);
            
    });
```

```html
<form id="formmath">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="unidades" name="unidades[]">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="valor" name="valorUnit[]">
<br><br/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="unidades" name="unidades[]">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="valor" name="valorUnit[]">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```